# Create d3d drawlines function to draw inside panel tab at index 0

Tags: c++, direct3d

I have the following code that draw lines on whole form:

```
 /*  Create GridLines */
 bool CreateGridLines()
{
 RECT rcTabControl;

 GetWindowRect(hwndTabControl, &rcTabControl);
 app_scale_x = (float)((rcTabControl.right - rcTabControl.left) / 96.0);
 app_scale_y = (float)((rcTabControl.bottom - rcTabControl.top) / 96.0);

 /* Get desktop DPI. 
 HDC screen = GetDC(0);
 app_scale_x = (float)(GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSX) / 96.0);
 app_scale_y = (float)(GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSX) / 96.0);
 ReleaseDC(0, screen);*/

 d3d_object = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

 /* Fill out the presentation parameters for the D3D device... windowed mode. */
 D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS present;
 fill_out_present(&present, hwnd);


 UINT AdapterToUse = D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT;
 D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType = D3DDEVTYPE_HAL;

 d3d_object->CreateDevice(AdapterToUse, DeviceType, hwnd,
                         D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE | D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                         &present, &d3d_device);

 if (!d3d_device) return false;

 return true; 
}
```

The problem is how can i draw this lines inside panel index 0? I get this source code script from:

```
http://braid-game.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/proof.cpp
```

I defined and initialized panel like this:

```
 HWND        hwndTabControl;

    /*  CreateTabControl */
 HWND CreateTabControl(HWND hwndParent)
{
 RECT rcClient;
 INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
 HBITMAP bmpMain;
 HIMAGELIST hwndImageList;
 TCITEM tie;

 /*  Initialize common controls */
 icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
 icex.dwICC  = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
 InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

 /*  Create a TabControl of child window size */
 GetClientRect(hwndParent, &rcClient);

 hwndTabControl = CreateWindowEx (
           0,
           WC_TABCONTROL,
           "",
           WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,
           0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,
           hwndParent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

 if (hwndTabControl == NULL)
 {
    return NULL;
 };

 /* Create ImageList */
hwndImageList = ImageList_Create(12, 9, ILC_COLOR24 | ILC_MASK, 0, 1);
bmpMain =(HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL, "0.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
ImageList_AddMasked(hwndImageList, bmpMain, RGB(255, 255, 255));

 /*  Add Tabs to panel */
 tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_IMAGE;
 tie.iImage = 0;
 tie.pszText = "Untitled";

 if ((TabCtrl_InsertItem(hwndTabControl, 0, &tie) == -1) || (TabCtrl_SetImageList(hwndTabControl, hwndImageList)))
 {
       DestroyWindow(hwndTabControl);
       return NULL;
 }

 /* PanelTab Default font */
 SendMessage(hwndTabControl, WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), MAKELPARAM(1,0));

 return hwndTabControl;
}
```

i just changed:

```
fill_out_present(&present, hwnd);
```

to

```
fill_out_present(&present, hwndTabControl);
```

but grid is draw on whole form window...and i want it inside panel tab index 0...i think i need to give index at what lines need to be drawn...i get this on left and i need to get this on right picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [TabCtrl_AdjustRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760645(v=vs.85).aspx) to adjust the client rectangle to the actual display area before doing the calculations for width/height and line start/end points:

```
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwndTabControl, &rc); // rc will be set to the client area of the tab control
TabCtrl_AdjustRect(hwndTabControl, FALSE, &rc); // rc will be adjusted to the actual display area of the tab control
```

Currently the client rectangle of the tab control starts at 0,0 while you actually want it to start at the offset where the actual display area begins. That is why you are drawing all over the form.

Comment: Thanks...i try using your suggestion and i think i somewhere doing it wrong..i uploaded whole cpp source code...could you take a look where i im doing it wrong? It is the same behavior like in picture posted above...link https://ufile.io/md1lm

Comment: I found in MSDN win32 API that i need to construct for each TabControl Child Dialog Box and then i put draw lines on current selected tab dialog box...i missed dialog box and this is where components are added...i see now that i im drawing lines on whole TabControl Width and Height and this is why gridlines are all over TabControl..when i finish adding Dialog Box i will add it here